# Finding the root of a DAG in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a DAG in Neo4j and want to find the root node.

I tried this:

```
MATCH (r) WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(r) RETURN r
```

i.e. all nodes that are not a child of another node.  However this returned several thousand results; this is a DAG with only one root!

I took one of the returned nodes and looked at its neighbourhood.  It has both parents and children so my query is wrong.  But I can't spot where or why.

I'm using the beta neo4j-community-2.2.0-M03 so a bug can't be ruled out.  However all of this is through the Neo4j console.

Thanks very much for your help - Christopher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are very close to finding nodes with no inward relationships. You just needed to wrap the `not` in your where clause in parentheses.

```
MATCH r-->() 
WHERE NOT ( ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->r ) 
RETURN r
```

Update to answer. Here is a small directed acyclic graph with a single root node.

```
CREATE (a:Node {name:'A'})
CREATE (b:Node {name:'B'})
CREATE (c:Node {name:'C'})
CREATE (d:Node {name:'D'})
CREATE (e:Node {name:'E'})
CREATE (f:Node {name:'F'})
CREATE (g:Node {name:'G'})
CREATE (h:Node {name:'H'})
CREATE a-[:POINTS]->b
CREATE a-[:POINTS]->c
CREATE c-[:POINTS]->d
CREATE c-[:POINTS]->e
CREATE c-[:POINTS]->f
CREATE f-[:POINTS]->g
CREATE f-[:POINTS]->h
```

When I query it with the following query I only get one root back. I am using community 2.2.0-M03 as well.

```
MATCH (r:Node)-->() 
WHERE NOT ( ()-->r ) 
RETURN r
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the two queries return the same results.

Comment: np. i added an example that works to the answer. Are you sure you only have one root in your data?

Comment: Thanks again, I did some experiments on your example and the results surprised me.

First I created the example tree by pasting the first line into the console and then the remaining lines.  This did not work!  Your query did not return any data and using "match (a) return a" showed a gray unlabelled top node and a disconected "a" node.

I then deleted the graph and recreated by pasting the entire example in one go.  This DID work, both the graph looked right with all nodes labelled and connected as expected and the query worked.

Comment: Just as an update.  I'm believe this is a bug in n4j and I suspect it is what is causing problems in my larger network.  I've raised an issue here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4043.  Thanks very much for your help.